# What does using clearInterval method accomplish that setting an interval variable reference to null does not?

Tags: javascript

I have a reset method in a JavaScript service file that resets all variables in the service to null. Some of the variables hold interval timer references. I noticed that using the reset method seems to cancel the intervals (that should not actually be the case, but it does appear to be in my Angular app).

My question is, does setting the interval reference to null have the same effect as formally clearing the interval with clearInterval(name)? Are there any technical differences I should be aware of?

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function () { console.log('interval fired'); }, 500);

// Are these two equivalent?
myInterval = null;
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

I notice that there seems to be a WindowTimers interface in the spec, and that is where the clearInterval method comes from. My guess is that calling clearInterval removes the named reference from some kind of list or array. If I set the timer to null, is it being left in the WindowTimers list as a null object that just can't be executed?

Comment: setInterval returns integer (ID), not reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interval timer "handle", or whatever you want to call it, is just a number. It identifies the timer to the runtime, but it's otherwise not anything special. The value sitting in a variable doesn't make the variable any more special than any other value, so resetting the variable to `null` has no effect on the timer at all.

You can open up your browser developer console and type this:

```
console.log(setTimeout(function(){}, 1))
```

and you'll see a number. Run it a few times and you'll see a sequence of increasing numbers.

Comment: So the WindowTimers.clearInterval(x) is actually using a numeric id to identify the particular timer in it's list. Is there any way you know of to log the timers list? I notice that timeouts and intervals increment the same list id.

Comment: Yes I think in all browsers there's just one set of timer identifiers; that also means that both `clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()` will clear either a `setTimeout()` timer or a `setInterval()` timer.  I don't know of any API to get a list of currently active timers, in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the myInterval variable to null will not stop the interval.
You can see that if you try that code in the Developer Tools in Chrome. Only after calling clearInterval the console.log calls stops.

Comment: This is true, in the dev tools it did not stop it. In my Angular app, it did stop it, so I'm not sure what the difference is, but that is probably a separate question.